# appSpot does not find my public posts

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-plus

Testing several plus feeds -

Made my [own app](http://mhpgplusfeed.appspot.com/117500723574087130516) from [this post](http://softwareas.com/make-your-own-google-plus-feed) which gives `list index out of range` and then found plu.sr but nothing is showing as if I never posted anything public.

Please help me find out why my public GPlus posts are not found here [plu.sr](http://plu.sr/feed.php?plusr=117500723574087130516) nor here:
[mhpgplusfeed](http://mhpgplusfeed.appspot.com/117500723574087130516) (the latter running the code from [git/plusfeed](https://github.com/russellbeattie/plusfeed))

I only get the one error in the app engine:

```
2011-12-04 07:26:30.291 /117500723574087130516 500 246ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:9.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0

83.84.44.152 - - [04/Dec/2011:07:26:30 -0800] "GET /117500723574087130516 HTTP/1.1" 500 199 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:9.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/9.0" "mhpgplusfeed.appspot.com" ms=246 cpu_ms=70 api_cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0.003448 instance=00c61b117c2de2439536d6fffb3f82b6a3324a

D 2011-12-04 07:26:30.053

re-requesting feed

E 2011-12-04 07:26:30.289

list index out of range
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably doesn't work because it [uses](https://github.com/russellbeattie/plusfeed/blob/master/plusfeed.py#L220) an [unofficial google+ api](https://plus.google.com/104298156070730115178/posts/99SCeHqge2o) that they must have secured at some point. The [object](https://github.com/russellbeattie/plusfeed/blob/master/plusfeed.py#L243) that's supposed to contain the feed contains some gibberish and in effect you get index out of range caught [here](https://github.com/russellbeattie/plusfeed/blob/master/plusfeed.py#L368). [This](https://github.com/russellbeattie/plusfeed/blob/master/plusfeed.py#L251) is the line that causes it. There's an [official API](https://developers.google.com/+/api/) available.

Comment: +1 thanks! So how to fix it? Do you know a gplus rss that works or is the program I use from GIT fixaple?

Comment: Found the official api and signed up. Will write/find a json2atom parser and host it myself

Comment: Oh, groovy. I've never worked with it to be honest. There is a client library for Python and a starter kit in the downloads section of the API site. Could be useful.

Comment: For what I want to do, it is VERY simple to write. Just need to grok PHP associative arrays after hitting it with json_decode :)